Can you insert HTML comments in the output of a MediaWiki article/page?
MediaWiki has first-class support for comments using HTML's <!--...--> syntax, but it always strips them from the output.
I think that's for a good reason, but I would like to have templates which leave an invisible "signature" pointing to themselves, similar to the very much visible V-T-E buttons of a navbox.

Could you not add another html element that you just hide using css and add the information there? This actually works : My template

I believe so, as suggested here for example, but that's only possible if I can edit global CSS overrides.
